# how can i trigger my AJAX if my data in my mysql database change

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, codeigniter

I am having a problem in refreshing of my data in my span tag. I need to refresh my span tag every 5 seconds because the data in my database is dynamic it is always changing.

For now I am using `setInterval` in my AJAX.

```
setInterval(get_value, 5000);

  function get_value(){
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url + ""
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
           //refresh the span tag
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown.message);
      }
    });
  }
```

But I think this is not the right way, this is very not good because of the response. Is there any way I could do this better using Codeigniter? For now my idea is just like this and it is working, I am just worried from my idea.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Best bet is **Nodejs and Socket.Io**

Okay in as much as you wanted to build this with PHP and AJAX,
I highly and will always highly doing this with **Node.js**  and **socket.Io** if you really
care about more scalable and performant applications.

**Node.js** is design for something like this unlike

AJAX makes which makes use of expensive HTTP requests in relation to Node.js.
Another good advantage of Nodejs is that it is incredibly fast at
doing many kinds of I/O and is asynchronous. Consequently, the Node.js process is non-blocking which helps make it even faster.

Node.js allows to handle many persistent connections with low memory usage,latency mitigations
which is quite suitable for handling all chat and realtime clients messages and calls.

There is a library for working with Nodejs called **Socket.Io**.  This
socket.io is an abstraction over websockets that allows to pass messages between the node server
and a web browser

Take a look at it. They are very interesting. Below are their source links

https://nodejs.org/en/

http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

Use Pusher for broadcasting your data from server side to client side. It uses websocket technology. If a specific page is updated then data is sent to pusher server and can catch that data from your client side( where you are showing your chart) using javascript.

If you use ajax it would drain your bandwidth much more than using pusher.

You can choose Redis, firebase, pubnub if you don't like pusher.